# How to replace single row in Matrix using Jama ?

Tags: java, jama

I trying to replace a single row using [Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/) .

I tried it by using `setMatrix` like this  -

```
double[][] myArray = { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1 } }; // all the matrix '1'
        Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix(myArray);

        myMatrix.setMatrix(2, 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new Matrix(
                new double[][] { { 3, 3, 3, 3 } })); // replace 2nd row to [3,3,3,3]
        System.out.println((Arrays.deepToString(myMatrix.getArray())));
```

but it throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` , how to make that correctly  ?

Comment: I managed - it just start from index 0  - change to  `{0,1,2,3}` .

Comment: then you should post your own answer and accept

Comment: I think I haven't this "badges"

Answer (score 0):

I managed - it just start from index 0 - change to `{0,1,2,3}`